# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel', but it requires model another model in project

Tags: sitecore-client, mvc, glass-mapper

In a sitecore mvc project created a .cshtml as mainlayout with the following code in it:

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation

@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<project.MVC.Models.Shared.IPageBase>

@{
    Layout = null;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>SampleLayout</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I assigned this as mainlayout to one of the item in Sitecore and previewed it.
Following is the error displayed:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Project.MVC.Models.Shared.IPageBase'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Disclaimer: I work with Indra and helped him solve the problem. Adding the answer with other issues that were resolved.

Dheeraj answer was right to the question. But unfortunately it opened up a new issue called `key not found` exception using Glass Mappper. This was because the model properties and item fields were not matching.

After ignoring the properties to AutoMap, faced another issue. This time it is with the `Glass.Mapper.Sc.Start.Config` file. The namespace mentioned for the `App_Start` method was not pointing to the project namespace. So, corrected it and everything started working properly.

Answer (score 2):

while you are inheriting from GlassView you need to do like below:

```
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<Interface name or Class name>
```

In your case you need to do like:

```
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<Project.MVC.Models.Shared.IPageBase>
```

If you are in old version of GlassMapper earlier to Glass V4 you need to specify the Model in your sitecore layout.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Dheeraj.I was tried.but I am getting error "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

Comment: can you post your full stacktrace? what version of glass you are on?

Comment: Make sure u have/deployed these configs "Glass.Mapper.Sc.config" and "Glass.Mapper.Sc.Start.config" if your glassMapper is prior to Glass4 "Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor.config" from the folder App_Config/Include